# Java inner class inconsistency between descriptor and signature attribute? (class file)

Tags: java, decompiling, .class-file

I'm trying to understand if there's a reason in the spec for the discrepany between java descriptors and signatures for inner classes. (I'm looking directly at the content of the class files here, but I use javap to illustrate).

( n.b.  I have tried this on JDK 1.6.0_33 and 1.7.0_05, both have the same issue *when viewed with javap from Java 7* - java 6's javap doesn't seem to show any generic signature info, as per Sean's answer below. )

Update : Thanks to those discussing - my take is

- The descriptor (which doesn't contain generic information) is correct.
- The signature (which is an attribute of the method, and does contain generic information) is incorrect.   The relevant ConstPool entry for SIGNATURE of the <init> method is " ConstantUTF8[(Ljava/util/list<TE;>)V] "
- Javap in Java 6 doesn't LOOK at the signature, just the descriptor. (My guess!)

In case anyone wonders, I hit this without using JAVAP, just looking at the class files myself, I am only using javap to show it. (so it's unlikely to be a javap bug).

Consider:

```
public class InnerClassTest1 {

  public int getX() {
    return new Inner1(new ArrayList<String>()).getX(4);
  }

  public class Inner1 {
    private final List arg;

    public Inner1(List arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }....
```

vs

```
public class InnerClassTest2 {

   public int getX() {
      return new Inner1(new ArrayList<String>()).getX(4);
   }

   public class Inner1<E> {
    private final List<E> arg;

    public Inner1(List<E> arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }.....
```

If you look at the output of javap -cs on the inner classes, they're surprisingly different!

public org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest1$Inner1(**org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest1,** java.util.List);
 Signature: (Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest1;Ljava/util/List;)V

vs

public org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest2$Inner1(java.util.List<E>);
 Signature: (Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2;Ljava/util/List;)V

... *the one which uses generics is missing the implicit parameter for the outer class!* (it's correctly present in InnerClassTest1).

I can't find anything in the class file documentation to explain this - does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks!

Lee.

---

Update -

I've placed example files at http://www.benf.org/files/innerClassTest.tgz

Given Sean's answer below, I tried using javap on java 6, and I saw identical output for both, with no generic information - this leads me to believe that java 6's javap is not displaying full signature information?

The exact output I get using javap on 1.7.0_05-b06 is

```
public class org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest2$Inner1<E> {
 final org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest2 this$0;
 Signature: Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2;

public org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest2$Inner1(java.util.List<E>);
 Signature: (Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2;Ljava/util/List;)V
 Code:
   0: aload_0       
   1: aload_1       
   2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2;
   5: aload_0       
   6: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   9: aload_0       
  10: aload_2       
  11: putfield      #3                  // Field arg:Ljava/util/List;
  14: return        

public int getX(int);
  Signature: (I)I
  Code:
   0: iconst_2      
   1: ireturn       
}
```

Comment: Please, specify JDK details

Comment: Could you post the actual class files? That would at least narrow it down to a compiler problem vs a disassembler problem.

Comment: Yes, I've amended the question with this.  They are here - http://www.benf.org/files/innerClassTest.tgz .  As per my amend, it's also interesting that javap (under java 6) seems to ignore generic signature information here.

Comment: The actual descriptors are fine, but `javap` isn't printing them. Must be a bug in Javap.

Comment: On second thought, this is probably an intentional "feature" in Javap. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code above and using JDK 1.6.0_33 I get the following output:

```
src\test>javap -c -s InnerClassTest1$Inner1
Compiled from "InnerClassTest1.java"
public class test.InnerClassTest1$Inner1 extends java.lang.Object{
final test.InnerClassTest1 this$0;
  Signature: Ltest/InnerClassTest1;

public test.InnerClassTest1$Inner1(test.InnerClassTest1, java.util.List);
  Signature: (Ltest/InnerClassTest1;Ljava/util/List;)V
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield        #1; //Field this$0:Ltest/InnerClassTest1;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   invokespecial   #2; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   9:   aload_0
   10:  aload_2
   11:  putfield        #3; //Field arg:Ljava/util/List;
   14:  return

public int getX(int);
  Signature: (I)I
  Code:
   0:   iload_1
   1:   ireturn
}

src\test>javap -c -s InnerClassTest2$Inner1
Compiled from "InnerClassTest2.java"
public class test.InnerClassTest2$Inner1 extends java.lang.Object{
final test.InnerClassTest2 this$0;
  Signature: Ltest/InnerClassTest2;

public test.InnerClassTest2$Inner1(test.InnerClassTest2, java.util.List);
  Signature: (Ltest/InnerClassTest2;Ljava/util/List;)V
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield        #1; //Field this$0:Ltest/InnerClassTest2;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   invokespecial   #2; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   9:   aload_0
   10:  aload_2
   11:  putfield        #3; //Field arg:Ljava/util/List;
   14:  return

public int getX(int);
  Signature: (I)I
  Code:
   0:   iload_1
   1:   ireturn

}
```

and the only differences are that my implementation has (to make the code compile):

```
    public int getX(int i) {
        return i;
    }
```

and the fact that your package name is probably different (org.benf.cfr.tests ?).

Other than that though, my output is pretty much the same.  Are there any other differences in the code that might explain what you're seeing? From what I know about the compilation process and class files I wouldn't expect to see a difference in the output.

Good question - be interesting to find out why you're seeing this

Comment: That's very interesting -   Perhaps it's something peculiar to my environment, though I have no idea what that could be! I've put up my /exact/ output, as well as class files [link](http://www.benf.org/files/innerClassTest.tgz) here, if you want to have a look.

Comment: I wonder if java 6's (are you using that?) javap is doing something different here, as I don't see any generic information in the output you have for InnerClassTest2.

Comment: I've downloaded your files and did javap -c -p on them and the output is identical to the above (with the exception of the package being different) - so it looks like javap is the culprit

Comment: I'm using javap -c -s <Class name>, and the java version I have is: java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: re: generic output in javap - I didnt even know that was possible, given that I thought that information wasnt present after compilation, but given your output maybe it is?  I'd be suprised though, as generics wasnt meant to change the class files generated in jdk5 onwards

Comment: I've done some research and it seems some generic information is retained in the class (learnt something new!). Additionally I think that jdk6 javap doesnt show it, and jdk7 does - can you check that you used jdk6 for both comparisons?  is it possible you used jdk6 javap for 1 and jdk7 javap for the other (just a guess here)

Comment: @Sean Generics (along with inner classes) are retained through optional attributes. They have no effect on the actual execution of the bytecode, but they are used for reflection and compiling against class files. They're essentially comments as far as the JVM is concerned.

Comment: Yes, the generic information is retained, as attributes on the class / method.  In this case, the issue is that the <init> method has a correct Descriptor, but the Signature is " (Ljava/util/List<TE;>;)V ".   I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javap on `InnerClassTest2$Inner1` gives

```
Compiled from "InnerClassTest2.java"
public class org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest2$Inner1<E> {
  final org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest2 this$0;
  public org.benf.cfr.tests.InnerClassTest2$Inner1(java.util.List<E>);
  public int getX(int);
}
```

Disassembling with Krakatau gives

```
.version 51 0
.source InnerClassTest2.java
.class super public org/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2$Inner1
.super java/lang/Object

.field final private arg Ljava/util/List;
.field synthetic final this$0 Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2;

.method public <init> : [_13]
    .limit stack 2
    .limit locals 3
    aload_0
    aload_1
    putfield org/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2$Inner1 this$0 Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2;
    aload_0
    invokespecial java/lang/Object <init> ()V
    aload_0
    aload_2
    putfield org/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2$Inner1 arg Ljava/util/List;
    return
.end method

.method public getX : (I)I
    .limit stack 1
    .limit locals 2
    iconst_2
    ireturn
.end method

.const [_13] = Utf8 (Lorg/benf/cfr/tests/InnerClassTest2;Ljava/util/List;)V
```

As you can see, the Krakatau output shows that the descriptor is actually correct, but for some reason Javap isn't displaying it. One thing about Javap is that it tries to arrange the output so it looks more like Java. Perhaps this is a new feature introduced in JDK7 that tries to make disassembled generics look more like Java by hiding the compiler added parameters. Unfortunately this makes Javap (even more) useless for seeing what's really there.

Interesting catch!