# How to declare optional basic type in scala e.g. Option[Int] so that the type gets seen as Option<Integer> from java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Consider the following scala class:

```
class Demo {
  def mandatoryInt: Int = 42

  def optInt: Option[Int] = Some(1)

  def optString: Option[String] = Some("demo")
}
```

When its methods are accessed from Java code, `optString` has type `Option<String>`.
However, method `optInt` has type `Option<Object>`.

I guess, it's because basic types are mapped to primitive java types. E.g. `mandatoryInt` has type `int` in Java. And `Option<int>` is not a valid java type.

Does anyone have an idea how to declare optional basic type in scala so that it gets normally inferred in java (i.e. `Option[Int]` to be seen as `Option<Integer>`)?

(Scala version 2.12.10, although I doubt that it matters much for my question)

Comment: Well you can just use `Option[Integer]` in **Scala** - Even best, write a `interface` in **Java** returning `Optional<Integer>` and implement that in **Scala** using the `jdk` package.

Comment: In such cases, [I tend to recommend the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835404/how-to-instantiate-a-nested-generic-class-defined-in-scala-from-java/48836719#48836719): provide a separate, idiomatic Java-interface. Implement that interface in Scala, then use only the Java-specific interface from Java. Java's type system is way more restricted, and all the metaprogramming stuff has no corresponding counterparts on Java's side anyway (who's supposed to plug in all the `given`s on Java side?), so it's usually less pain for everyone involved to provide a Java-specific APIs.

Comment: Amplifying on @AndreyTyukin, it may be worth looking at the general approach taken in Akka to have a `javadsl` implemented in Scala.